# Do microwaves (photons) lose energy as they heat?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves, dissipation

I understand that microwaves are able to heat water because their alternating electromagnetic fields flip water molecules (dipoles) up and down which increases the waters kinetic energy (thus increasing temperature).
Doesn't that mean the microwave photons are then losing energy due to law of the conservation of energy?

In other words, if I took a single microwave photon (~30 cm wavelength) and passed it through a cup of water, **would it come out the other side with a larger wavelength** (because it lost energy interacting with the H2O's)?

Comment: What you should have clear in thinking of light is that light emerges from zillions of photons but a photon is not light. In the same way a building is made out of thousands of bricks but a brick is not a building. This might help   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, lets calculate the energy per photon for a 30 cm radiation:

$$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda} = \frac{(6.62\times10^{-34}\ {\rm Js})(3\times10^8\ {\rm m/s})}{30\times10^{-2}\ {\rm m}} = 6.62\times10^{-25}\ {\rm J}$$

That means that a 1000 W microwave oven is producing in the neighborhood of $1.5\times10^{27}$ photons per second (or $6.1\times10^{26}$ photons per second at the more typical microwave oven wavelength of 12 cm), and the energy associated with each individual photon is miniscule.

When the water absorbs energy from the electromagnetic wave, it absorbs whole photons rather than taking only part of the energy from a photon. The vast number of photons involved in the interaction means that the energy in the EM wave can essentially change continuously (the water can absorb 10% of the energy or 10.01% or 10.10203910% of the energy without having to only "partially absorb" a photon).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. How did you go from 6.62×10 −25  J to 7×10 31  
7×1031 photons per second? Thanks.

Comment: @BradS, by screwing up. Edited now.

Comment: @ThePhoton Im confused. What is making the water molecule move? Is it the alternative electric field or is it because it is absorbing microwave photons?

Comment: @Nova, those are just two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: @ThePhoton That can't be true. Why is it then that water heats up in a microwave but ice doesn't? If water simply absorbs the microwave photon, then the phase water is in shouldn't matter..

Comment: @Nova, liquid water selectively absorbs radiation at certain frequencies because of the structure of the water molecule. We choose the frequency used in our microwave oven to be the highly absorbed frequencies because most of our food contains water. Ice doesnt' absorb the same frequencies in the microwave range because the neighboring molecules are more tightly coupled together, reducing each molecule's freedom of motion. This is true whether we talk about absorbing photons with certain energies or interacting with a classical field with a certain frequency (two ways to say the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the microwave photon is absorbed by a water molecule, so any re-radiation you get out the other side wouldn't be the same photon anymore.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.businessinsider.com/how-do-microwaves-work-2014-6

"The positively charged end of the water molecule tries to align itself with the microwave's electric field while the negatively charged end points the other way. But because the field reverses 2.5 billion times a second, Mickey's ears and face are being twisted back and forth rapidly."

(The molecule as illustrated in the referenced text resembles the rounded head and ears of Mickey Mouse)

What you get isn't so much a LONGER wavelength compared to the energy being absorbed, so much as a SHORTER wavelength (infrared) produced by the action described above (the dipoles of the water molecules twisting rapidly back and forth).  A microwave photon may do this many times, being reflected and re-entering the water or food being heated until it is heated to the desired temperature.  The interior of the microwave oven is a tuned cavity. Any foodstuffs heated in there detune the cavity, and if it is working properly and the rest of the interior of the microwave oven is relatively clean, it is quite efficient (60-70%).   Some energy loss is also dissipated in the magnetron in the form of heat, which is once again, a shorter wavelength than the microwaves that do the actual cooking..